# Where to find a comprehensive review of Butcher's tableau and dense step expressions for most used RK methods?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, runge-kutta-methods

I need to implement several RK methods with adaptive timestep.

I am however wasting a lot of time in finding consistently Butcher's tableau AND the expressions to evaluate the solution on dense steps. They seem to be dispersed over several publications, and figuring out if they are consistent is taking up a lot of my time.

I am in particular looking for methods like DP54 and TSI54, with different orders for the interpolant.

Can you suggest some reference/review where to find Butcher's tableau AND dense step expressions?

It would also be great if the reference gave any suggestion for optimal parameters for step control techniques.

Thanks!

Comment: differentialequations.jl has a comprehensive collection of intensely tested methods, with implementations directly from Butcher tableaus and step routines coded for memory economy and elimination of trivial computations (zero coefficients).

Comment: Thanks. I was already using their Butcher tableaus, by browsing the code, however I cannot find the expressions for the dense output. Do you know where they are?

Comment: This sounds like the hard-coded examples. There is also a general routine to just load the coefficients for general RK methods, there should then also be a database somewhere of the tableaus, including the dense output coefficients.

Comment: I found the database with the tableaus. However I could not find the dense output coefficients. Do you have an idea where they might be?

Comment: No, I have no idea where to look. I know that they are used in tests, as discussed in https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/24998/which-runge-kutta-method-is-more-accurate, and necessary for event-handling and DDE solvers, as said in https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/25581/why-are-higher-order-runge-kutta-methods, but not every method has known interpolators and some have multiple, there can be multiple approaches to handle this logistically.